# Reduce time complexity of brute forcing - largest prime factor

Tags: python, c, performance

I am writing a code to find the largest prime factor of a very large number.

> Problem 3 of Project Euler  : 
>    What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I coded it in C...but the data type long long int is not sufficient enough to hold the value .

Now, I have rewritten the code in Python.  How can I reduce the time taken for execution (as it is taking a considerable amount of time)?

```
def isprime(b):
    x=2
    while x<=b/2:
        if(b%x)==0:
            return 0
        x+=1
    return 1
def lpf(a):
    x=2
    i=2
    while i<=a/2:
        if a%i==0:
            if isprime(i)==1:
                if i>x:
                    x=i
                    print(x)
        i+=1
    print("final answer"+x)
z=600851475143
lpf(z)
```

Comment: `long long int` is enough to hold that number.

Comment: 600851475143 fits in a `long long int` just fine, it's much less than 2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807.

Comment: suggest migration to codereview

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write C code in Python. Read about `for` loops, `xrange`, and the `bool` type, for starters.

Comment: 6857 is the largest prime factor of 600851475143 - its factors are 71, 839, 1471 and 6857. Took less than 20ms with a brute-force sieve-like program I wrote some time ago called rather imaginatively `factor`...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code, and may be better handled on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, you may want to first look on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) for a decent-but-simple algorithm (although really, it's probably easier to find one elsewhere on the net), and then try to implement it, instead of starting with an implementation and trying to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible algorithmic speed ups. Some basic ones might be:

- First, if you are only interested in the **largest** prime factor, you should check for them **from the largest possible** ones, not smallest. So instead of looping from `2` to `a/2` try to check **from** `a` downto `2`.
- You could load the database of primes instead of using `isprime` function (there are dozens of such files in the net)
- Also, only odd numbers can be primes (except for `2`) so you can "jump" 2 values in each iteration

Your `isprime` checker could also be speededup, you do not have to look for divisiors up to `b/2`, it is enough to check to `sqrt(b)`, which reduces complexity from `O(n)` to `O(sqrt(n))` (assuming that modulo operation is constant time).

Comment: @delnan: Obviously I get your point. But if you were writing a serious prime factorization program, you may very well memoize it, and seed the memoization cache with a pre-existing database, right? So long as you write code that still works properly even beyond the limits of that database, using the database isn't really cheating…

Comment: @abarnert Actually, I doubt the typical "serious" factorization applications benefit from memoization. When numbers get huge, you don't use trial division (exclusively, obviously it's a good way to get the first few factors) and more efficient algorithms don't seem to (explicitly) decide primality a lot or at all, i.e. there is no `isprime()` to speed up. In any case, this is a project euler question and what's useful for serious applications isn't useful for this question. The requirements are just too different.

Comment: @delnan: There are different kinds of serious factorization programs—searching for undiscovered primes is different from cracking encryption algorithms. But more generally, point taken.

Comment: i found a recursive solution on stack overflow .. but your answer ..points 1 and 3 helped .

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree with the first point, but I may be wrong. Prime factors are going to be less dense higher in the range, so the number of iterations needed to find them will be greater. I think it would still be better to fully factor the number starting from 2 up to `sqrt(a)`, and every time you find a factor `f`, you stop trying to factor `a`, and start trying to factor `a/f` from `f` up to `sqrt(a/f)`. I haven't done a full complexity analysis on that though, just a "gut instinct"... Also, for point 3, once you get past 5, it should only be odd numbers ending in 1, 3, 7 or 9...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the 128 int provided by GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html . This way, you can continue to use C and avoid having to optimize Python's speed. In addition, you can always add your own custom storage type to hold numbers bigger than long long in C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're checking too many numbers (incrementing by 1 and starting at 2 in each case). If you want to check is_prime by trial division, you need to divide by fewer numbers: only odd numbers to start (better yet, only primes). You can range over odd numbers in python the following way:

```
for x in range(3, some_limit, 2):
    if some_number % x == 0:
      etc.
```

In addition, once you have a list of primes, you should be able to run through that list backwards (because the question asks for highest prime factor) and test if any of those primes evenly divides into the number.

Lastly, people usually go up to the square-root of a number when checking trial division because anything past the square-root is not going to provide new information. Consider 100:

```
1 x 100
2 x 50
5 x 20
10 x 10
20 x 5
etc.
```

You can find all the important divisor information by just checking up to the square root of the number. This tip is useful both for testing primes and for testing where to start looking for a potential divisor for that huge number.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your two while loops only need to go up to the sqrt(n) since you will have hit anything past that earlier (you then need to check a/i for primeness as well). In addition, if you find the lowest number that divides it, and the result of the division is prime, then you have found the largest.

First, correct your `isprime` function:

```
def isprime(b):
    x=2
    sqrtb = sqrt(b)
    while x<=sqrtb:
        if(b%x)==0:
            return 0
        x+=1
    return 1
```

Then, your lpf:

```
def lpf(a):
    x=2
    i=2
    sqrta = sqrt(a)
    while i<=sqrt(a):
        if a%i==0:
            b = a//i # integer
            if isprime(b):
                return b
            if isprime(i):
                x=i
                print(x)
        i+=1
    return x
```